# Consolidate array of numbers without exceeding a predefined maximum value per element

Tags: php, arrays, max

I'm trying to combine numbers in an array by adding them so that the max value can only by 30.

For example, this is my array:

```
array(10,30,10,10,15);
```

After combining the numbers in the array to items with a max value 30, the result should be:

```
array(30,30,15);
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide some code to show you tried.

Comment: i think this question needs to be clarified. Are you asking for a way to take an array of numbers, then combine them by getting the total of all the numbers in the array, and making a new array that is filled with values that add up (sum) to the same value as the orignal array but no value above 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to combine numbers in an array by adding them so that the
>   max value can only by 30

So, when you combine numbers, you can achieve the lowest possible set of values in your array and also make sure that max value remains 30 by:

- First, sort them.
- Second, keeping adding elements to sum till you are about to get a sum > 30.
- Third, once an element can no longer be added to a sum, add the current sum in your array and make the current element as the new sum.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = array(10,30,10,10,15);
sort($arr);

$res = [];
$curr_sum = 0;

foreach($arr as $each_value){
    if($curr_sum + $each_value <= 30) $curr_sum += $each_value;
    else{
        $res[] = $curr_sum;
        $curr_sum = $each_value;
    }
}

$res[] = $curr_sum;

print_r($res);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/BYhuE

**Update:** If order of the numbers matters, seeing your current output, you could just use [rsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) to show them in descending order.

```
rsort($res);
```

Comment: you need to sort array by value size as this outputs Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 15 [2] => 30 )  when the op asks for Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 30 [2] => 15 ) .

Comment: @Clint I don't think the order matters. OP never mentioned it. I have added an update If that matters to the OP.

Comment: test this with array(110,30,10,10,5,6,7,13,50,15) appears to give Array
(
    [0] => 28,
    [1] => 23,
    [2] => 15,
    [3] => 30,
    [4] => 50,
    [5] => 110
)

Comment: @Clint The test case doesn't make sense! `110` itself is above `30`. How could you expect this to be combined or individually exist without breaking the rule? OP never said you could eliminate values from the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = array_sum(array(10,30,10,10,15)); //assign sum totals from orignal array
$maxValue = 30; //assign max value allowed in array
$numberOfWholeOccurancesOfMaxValue = floor($total/$maxValue);
$remainder = $total%$maxValue;

//build array
$i=0;
while ( $i < $numberOfWholeOccurancesOfMaxValue ){
    $array[] = $maxValue;
    $i++;
}

$array[] = $remainder;

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Check your answer for [test case](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15c286e8a42143930855958ef4f65466eed37f2c)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3c9c00ac8f4016a58089941e5f2ea85832b989f - works?

Comment: @quickSwap  i replied to your main post

Answer (score 0):

You can loop only once to get this,

```
$temp = array(10,30,10,10,15);
natsort($temp); // sorting to reduce hustle and complication
$result = [];
$i = 0;
$maxValue = 30;
foreach($temp as $v){
    // checking sum is greater or value is greater or $v is greater than equal to
    if(!empty($result[$i]) && (($result[$i]+$v) > $maxValue)){
        $i++;
    }
    $result[$i] = (!empty($result[$i]) ? ($result[$i]+$v) : $v);
}
print_r($result);
```

[**Working demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f44d3d3f2ce26c38d9c412aca9896e3e42ac53a2).

Comment: this give output Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 25 [2] => 30 )  which is not what the op wants.

Comment: I updated my answer. And yes, order won't hamper OP. so we better keep that way.

Comment: testing with array array(10,30,10, 70, 30, 1,1,3,6 ,10,15); givesArray
(
    [0] => 21,
    [1] => 20,
    [2] => 15,
    [3] => 30,
    [4] => 30,
    [5] => 70
)

Comment: I am sure, no-one would know the format output required except OP. So, yours also wrong that way. So its uncertainty.

Comment: it is my understand that the op is looking for an array with all the values added up but no value larger than 30? so  Array
(
    [0] => 30,
    [1] => 30,
    [2] => 30,
    [3] => 30,
    [4] => 30,
    [5] => 30,
    [6] => 6
)

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear, whether OP wants to round to 30.

Comment: hi, yeah im doubting myself now. i asked the OP to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I believe finding most space-optimized/compact result requires a nested loop. My advice resembles the `firstFitDecreasing()` function in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74966903/2943403) except in this case the nested loops are accessing the same array. I've added a couple of simple conditions to prevent needless iterations.

```
rsort($array);
foreach ($array as $k1 => &$v1) {
    if ($v1 >= $limit) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($array as $k2 => $v2) {
        if ($k1 !== $k2 && $v1 + $v2 <= $limit) {
            $v1 += $v2;
            unset($array[$k2]);
            if ($v1 === $limit) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
rsort($array);
var_export($array);
```

By putting larger numbers before smaller numbers before processing AND by attempting to add multiple subsequent values to earlier values, having fewer total elements in the result is possible.

See [my comparative demonstration](https://3v4l.org/a6tCk).

1. I believe @Clint's answer is misinterpreting the task and is damaging the data by summing all values then distributing the max amounts in the result array.
2. With more challenging input data like `$array = [10,30,5,10,5,13,14,15,10,5];` and `$limit = 30;`, my solution provides a more dense result versus @nice_dev's and @rahul's answers.