# Populate array with subarrays which have a max sum from flat array of numbers

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, fill

I need to fill an array which may contain an indeterminate number of subarrays (pallets) -- each with a maximum size of 265cm.

I have a flat array of integers (packs) which need to be optimally arranged in pallets (for example 50cm, 45cm, 30cm, ...).

How can I dynamically create a system that creates the multidimensional array that represents pallets with the best space optimization?

This is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $mix_cc; $i++) { 
    foreach ($sh_array as $key => $row) { 
        $cm_remaining = $default_cc_height_fa - $sh_size;
        $sh_size = $sh_size + $row['size'];                   
        if ($row['size'] < $cm_remaining) {
            $mix_cc_array[$cc_number][$key] = $sh_array[$key];                   
        } else {
            $mix_cc_array[$cc_number + 1][$key] = $sh_array[$key];             
        }
        unset($sh_array[$key]);
    }
    $cc_number++;   
}
```

Comment: The question for "the best space optimization" is not a programming question, but one for theoretical computer science. If you have a concrete algorithm that delivers the best space optimization, _then_ you can ask the programming question how to implement this algorithm in php.

Comment: Somewhat topically related: [How to combine values in array if max value can only be 30?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56356455/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize the space in the pallets, you can try the following First Fit Decreasing (FFD) approach:

Sort the array of packs by size in descending order. This way, you can start by adding the largest packs first and try to fit as many of them as possible in the pallet.

Iterate through the sorted array of packs and try to fit each pack in the current pallet. If the pack fits, add it to the pallet; If the pack does not fit, create a new pallet and add the pack to it.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates how you can implement this approach:

```
$default_cc_height_fa = 265; // size of the pallet in cm
$sh_array = [50, 45, 30, 60, 70, 80]; // array of packs

// sort the array of packs in decreasing order of size
usort($sh_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b - $a;
});

// initialize the array of pallets
$mix_cc_array = [];

// iterate through the array of packs
foreach ($sh_array as $pack) {
    // try to fit the pack into an existing pallet
    $packed = false;
    foreach ($mix_cc_array as &$pallet) {
        if ($pack <= $default_cc_height_fa - array_sum($pallet)) {
            $pallet[] = $pack;
            $packed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if the pack does not fit into any existing pallet, create a new one
    if (!$packed) {
        $mix_cc_array[] = [$pack];
    }
}

print_r($mix_cc_array);
```

Sandbox Example: https://onlinephp.io/c/45ca2

This should give you an array of pallets that are optimally packed in terms of space utilization using the First Fit Decreasing (FFD) method. You can also look into the Next Fit Decreasing (NFD) method if this one doesn't work for you.

Comment: tested with my datas. this is the result: [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 120
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 75
            [1] => 75
            [2] => 75
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
        )
is not optimized. with this values must be create only 2 pallet :(

Comment: try with $sh_array = [120, 100, 75, 75, 75, 60];
it can create 2 pallet with [120,75,60] and [100,75,75].

Comment: @SabinoSibillano Yes that is expected behavior because after the first two largest packs are added, there is no room for any other packs; so it creates a new pallet. Try looking into the aforementioned NFD method, maybe that could help. But in general, there is no correct way to do this, especially when dealing with large enough datasets; it is why this question is defined as an NP-hard problem.

Comment: Isn't `usort($sh_array, function($a, $b) { return $b - $a; });` just `rsort($sh_array);`?

Comment: please how it work with multidimensional array your code? @Crimin4L

Comment: @SabinoSibillano you did not provide a [mcve] in your question.  If you want answerers to a accommodate a certain data structure, you need to provide sample data and your exact desired output so that your requiremenrs are clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two succinct snippets to implement the [First Fit Decreasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-fit-decreasing_bin_packing) and [Next Fit Decreasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-fit-decreasing_bin_packing) algorithms.  I suspect you will lean toward the FFD algorithm because it attempts to fully pack early pallets before bothering to open a new one.  My understanding is that NDD is optimized for performance, but FFD is optimized for minimal pallets.

<sub>If my understanding of these algorithms is not entirely accurate, I am happy to be corrected.</sub>

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QSP6a))

```
function nextFitDecreasing(array $items, int $max): array
{
    rsort($items);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!isset($pallet) || (array_sum($pallet) + $item) > $max) {
            unset($pallet);
            $result[] = &$pallet;
        }
        $pallet[] = $item;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And

```
function firstFitDecreasing(array $items, int $max): array
{
    rsort($items);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        foreach ($result as &$pallet) {
            if (array_sum($pallet) + $item <= $max) {
                $pallet[] = $item;
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        $result[] = [$item];
    }
    return $result;
}
```