# Group array of rows and fill earliest group without exceeding capacity

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fill

I have a 2d array of "packs" with their own specified size in centimeters.  I need to optimally distribute these packs into a new 3d array to represent pallets of packs which each have a maximum capacity of 265cm.

[Current code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74943031/2943403) which works with a 1d array of sizes:

```
$default_cc_height_fa = 265; // size of the pallet in cm
$sh_array = [50, 45, 30, 60, 70, 80]; // array of packs

// sort the array of packs in decreasing order of size
usort($sh_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b - $a;
});

// initialize the array of pallets
$mix_cc_array = [];

// iterate through the array of packs
foreach ($sh_array as $pack) {
    // try to fit the pack into an existing pallet
    $packed = false;
    foreach ($mix_cc_array as &$pallet) {
        if ($pack <= $default_cc_height_fa - array_sum($pallet)) {
            $pallet[] = $pack;
            $packed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if the pack does not fit into any existing pallet, create a new one
    if (!$packed) {
        $mix_cc_array[] = [$pack];
    }
}

print_r($mix_cc_array);
```

How is it possible to adjust the above code to accommodate a 2d array like this:

```
$sh_array = [
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 50],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 45],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 30],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 60],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 70],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 80]
];
// array of array of packs
```

Of course, I need to manage the sizes, but I need entire rows of data (packs) to be pushed into the subarrays (pallets).

Comment: You could've kept this question within your [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942708/populate-array-with-subarrays-which-have-a-max-sum-from-flat-array-of-numbers) by simply editing it with new the information you provided here. Instead you just C&P'ed the code I provided you as "yours" without even mentioning the first post; pretty disingenuous, but I am glad you received the help you were looking for.

Comment: This the second question from you @Sabino that does not explicitly express the exact desired output from a sample set of data.  Please provide a [mcve] when you ask a question so that answers can be verified as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minor modifications, we can loop through an array of packs that have both `id` and `size` attributes. To make the comparison between the size of the current `pack` and the maximum height constant, we can also add attributes to the `pack` to accumulate everything.

Finally, because I was interested in exiting both loops, I used `continue 2` although you could keep your original `$packed = false;` approach as well.

```php
<?php
const DEFAULT_CC_HEIGHT_FA = 265; // size of the pallet in cm

// define array of products to add
$sh_array = [["id_product" => 13, "size" => 50],
            ["id_product" => 13, "size" => 45],
            ["id_product" => 13, "size" => 30],
            ["id_product" => 13, "size" => 60],
            ["id_product" => 13, "size" => 70],
            ["id_product" => 13, "size" => 80]];

// sort the array of packs in decreasing order of size
usort($sh_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b["size"] - $a["size"];
});

// initialize the array of pallets
$mix_cc_array = [];

// iterate through the array of packs
foreach ($sh_array as $listRow) {
    // try to fit the pack into an existing pallet
    foreach ($mix_cc_array as &$pallet) {

        $newHeight = $listRow["size"] + $pallet["totalHeight"];

        if ($newHeight <= DEFAULT_CC_HEIGHT_FA) {
            // add new pack to this pallet
            array_push($pallet["pallets"],$listRow);
            
            // update accumulators
            $pallet["palletsStored"] += 1;
            $pallet["totalHeight"] = $newHeight;

            // continue the outer loop
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    // if the pack does not fit into any existing pallet, create a new one
    $mix_cc_array[] = array("totalHeight"=> $listRow["size"],
        "palletsStored" => 1, "pallets" => [$listRow]);
}

print_r($mix_cc_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74966903/2943403) and this answer is how to sort and count the array data.  The algorithm remains the same.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qBrJ1))

```
$pallet_limit = 111;
$packs = [
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 50],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 45],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 30],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 60],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 70],
    ['id_product' => 13, 'size' => 80]
];

usort($packs, fn($a, $b) => $b["size"] <=> $a["size"]);

$pallets = [];
foreach ($packs as $pack) {
    foreach ($pallets as &$pallet) {
        if ((array_sum(array_column($pallet, 'size')) + $pack["size"]) <= $pallet_limit) {
            $pallet[] = $pack;
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $pallets[] = [$pack];
}
var_export($pallets);
```

1. Sort the rows by size value in a descending direction.
2. Iterate your array of products.
3. Iterate a new array where pallets will be stored.
4. If a given pack "fits" in an encountered pallet, push it into that pallet; otherwise check the subsequent pallets; if no pallet is suitable, create a new pallet and push the pack into it.